# Data Validation List Error

Tags: vba, excel, validation, excel-2010

I'm trying to add a data validation pulldown list, and I've been debugging it for a while to no avail.  I'm getting a Run-time error 1004, Application-defined or object defined error.  The error occurs in Formula1 setting part of the `Validation.Add` statement.

I've tried using a string reference to a named range, a string reference to a standard range, and, as shown below, a comma delimited list string generated from the list on the worksheet as shown in the code below.  I have checked the list string with `Debug.Print` and got the expected result.

```
Sub addPT_Validation()
Dim sValidationList As String
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.Names("PT_Puldown").RefersToRange
    sValidationList = sValidationList & cell.Value & ","
Next cell

sValidationList = Left(sValidationList, Len(sValidationList) - 1)

With ActiveSheet.Range("D14").Validation
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
            AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Operator:=xlEqual, _
            Formula1:=sValidationList
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All your code is working (certainly could be optimized), all you need to do is delete the validation if it already exists.

If you try to add validation to a cell which already contains one, you will get error 1004.

```
Sub addPT_Validation()
    Dim sValidationList As String
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.Names("PT_Puldown").RefersToRange
        sValidationList = sValidationList & cell.Value & ","
    Next cell

    sValidationList = Left(sValidationList, Len(sValidationList) - 1)

    With ActiveSheet.Range("D1").Validation
        '/Delete first., in case of any any existing validation
        .Delete

        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
                AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Operator:=xlEqual, _
                Formula1:=sValidationList
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the named range reference to build up the formula to put in `Formula1` parameter of `Validation` object `Add()` method, like follows

```
Sub addPT_Validation()
Dim formula As String

With ThisWorkbook.Names("PT_Puldown").RefersToRange
    formula = "'" & .Parent.Name & "'!" & .Address(External:=False) 
End With

With ActiveSheet.Range("D14").Validation
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
            AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Operator:=xlEqual, _
            Formula1:=formula
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: this is still going to fail and throw error 1004, code needs to delete any existing data validation for the cell before attempting add a new one.

Comment: @cyboashu, so let him add it! Funny that nobody cares about sheet reference in Formula1 parameter which, though not certain, seems almost a much probable issue from OP's code where a workbook scoped name is used for the list and an ActiveSheet reference for the cell bound to host it...

Comment: Don't take my comment otherwise. Just wanted to point out for sake of completion. Didn't intend to start any argument or criticize :)

Comment: @cyboashu, neither did I.

Comment: That was what I did at first.  The reason I used a somewhat odd method was that it was the last thing I tried before giving up!

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @cyboashu, your error is coming from the fact that you did not delete the validation before adding a new one.

With regard to your other issue of trying to pass the range to Formula1 directly:

Formula1 should refer to the range as a string.
eg:

```
Formula1:="=$G$2:$G$7"
```

or, using your variables:

```
Formula1:="=" & ThisWorkbook.Names("PT_Puldown").RefersToRange.Address
```

or, simpler:

```
Formula1:="=" & Range("PT_Puldown").Address
```

Comment: that's fine (not the best way) but you can pass string too and its acceptable. Error 1004 is due the missing delete statement.

Comment: @cyboashu I have not done any speed tests, but you can avoid the string construction coding by just passing the address to the argument.

Comment: @cyboashu  Oh, and I agree with you about the significance of the missing `delete`

Comment: Yes, totally agreed. but the actual issue here is deleting the existing validation before adding one, unless I am missing something :)

Comment: @cyboashu I agree, but he also wrote about an issue when trying to use a string reference to the range object.  He did not show what he used, and I responded to that part.  I will clarify my answer.

Comment: I fixed the delete part and I simplified the code to have `Formula1:="=PT_Puldown"` and it seems to be working fine, so I don't think that was part of the problem.  Also, I would have needed to add a worksheet reference for it to work as the range is on another sheet.

Comment: @nateAtwork Glad you got it working.  Note that if your `Defined Name` is `Workbook` in `Scope`  (and this is usually the default, with the sheet name being included as part of the defined name), then there would be no need, within your Macro, to add a worksheet reference.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I'm not sure what you mean by a `Defined Name` being `Workbook` in `Scope`.  I typically add names using the box to the left of the formula bar on the worksheet, and when I use the `Range.Address` property I just get the cell's address without the worksheet.  Unless there is another way to define names that I'm not aware of, I think you would need to use the worksheet property as well.

Comment: @nateAtwork When you define a name, look closely in the dialog box. You should be able to define it as being either of Workbook or Worksheet in scope.  If it is Workbook, you can access it from any worksheet.  If it is Worksheet, you will only only access it from the particular sheet. If it is Workbook scope, you will be able to access the range name no matter the activesheet.  If it is worksheet, then you can only access it from the worksheet on which it was defined.  In VBA, with a workbook scope name, you can return the worksheet name with `Range("MyRange").Worksheet.Name`